# Eclipse+Junit4+SpringFramework: Running an individual Unittest class caused "Failed to load ApplicationContext" Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit, junit4

If I run all unittests classes inside my project, the exception is not fired.

However, if I just select one individual class, a 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception will be thrown for the reason "Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Here is the stack trace:

```
2011-06-29 17:48:12,400 ERROR [main] - TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@75c744] to prepare test instance [com.ahwkong.work.MyTest@6d6aa0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:203)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:93)
      at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:130)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [ProjectDB.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'env.jdbc.url'
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:268)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:363)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
      at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
      at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:199)
      ... 16 more
```

The root cause is, as you can see, due to the placeholder resolution. The ProjectDB.xml file actually lives inside another jar file.

Why the difference in behavior? (all test classes vs one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env.jdbc.url` is not resolved. I would assume you are passing this as a JVM argument (or env variable), and you have this remembered as a run configuration for running all the tests, but it isn't set for individual tests.

Make sure you have all the required properties set from the Run dialog.

Comment: thanks, it works. I just need to add the labels and their values in the 'Environment' tab.